# Parse error on input,while compiling read File, process it and write result to another File code in Haskell

Tags: haskell, gf

When I compile below code in Haskell, I get following error:

*Error: parse error on input 'gr' in the line x*

```
 module Main where

 import PGF
 import System.Environment
 import System.IO

 main :: IO ()
 main = do
 file:_ <- getArgs
 gr     <- readPGF file
 content <- readFile "input.txt"
 writeFile "output.txt" &(translate gr content)


 translate :: PGF -> String -> String
    translate gr s = case parseAllLang gr (startCat gr) s of
    (lg,t:_):_ -> unlines [linearize gr l t | l <- languages gr, l /= lg]
    _ -> "NO PARSE"
```

In this code I want to read a line(string) from input file and bind it to content. after that pass the content and PGF file(gr) to translate function and finally write the processed string via translate function on output file.

What is wrong with this code, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't indent the definition of `translate`. It should line up directly below its type signature.

```
translate :: PGF -> String -> String
translate gr s = {- ... -}
```

*Do* indent the body of `main`. The line after `do` needs to be indented, otherwise the layout rule will dictate that everything following it is part of the `do` block.

I think you're borrowing `&` from another language. You should write that line as either

```
writeFile "output.txt" (translate gr content)
```

or

```
writeFile "output.txt" $ translate gr content
```

(Which are identical; the operator `$` is used in Haskell to eliminate the need for parentheses.)

Comment: I ommited intent, now error changed to: parse error on input '=' in line for definition of `translate` function.

Comment: I used `&` just for cast the result of translate function to pure string, or IO string, likely to solve this problem. This function just recieve PGF file that made from 2 GF files.

Comment: That's not how Haskell works. The output of `translate` is a `String`, which is exactly what `writeFile` wants.

Comment: I used brackets instead of `&`, but still the error(`parse error on input '=' ` in line for definition) exists. Do you think the logic of this code is correct?

Comment: You need to indent the body of `main` by at least one space. Otherwise `translate` is parsed as part of the `do` block in `main`, which is syntactically invalid.

Comment: No problem; the layout rule can be confusing, especially if you're coming from a C-style language. Check out the [Haskell wikibook chapter on indentation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation).